# passing data to the decryption function(php)

Tags: php

I am passing string to decryption function.I need to decrypt the string that is in hexadecimal format.

For example I pass '8AEBB779B8564E84F8F22541DDB098D00F194D0530BF7540' from database as string.

I have a doubt in the below php code if string is what is passed

Below I have attached my code,error log as well as database structure.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$query = "select encrypted_data from encrypted_data";
$rs = $dbhandle->query($query);

while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data['encrypted_data'] = $row;
    writeMsg($data, $dbhandle);

}

function writeMsg($data, $dbhandle) {
    $key = hex2bin('2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158908cf5f3c');
    $iv = hex2bin('f0f1f2f3f4f5f3f7f8f8fafbfdfdfefa');

    foreach ($data as $str) {
        $input = hex2bin($str);
    }
}
?>
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeGbc.png)

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8uBa.png)

Comment: What are you expecting $input to be? It will always be the last string. You need to concatenate it using Dot Equals i.e. $input .= hex2bin($str);

Comment: Thanks :) error was inside hex string. Had to use trim() before passing it for decryption -suggested by @jeroen

Answer (score 2):

The loop in your `writeMsg()` function iterates over all rows that you have found:

```
foreach($data as $str)
```

Here `$str` is a row from the `while` loop before that, an array.

So instead of:

```
$input=hex2bin($str);
```

You need:

```
$input=hex2bin($str['encrypted_data']);
```

Even if you only retrieve 1 column, a row will still be an array.

Comment: Thanks :) but I have an error 'undefined offset with $str' when code is changed to $input=hex2bin($str['encrypted_data']);

Comment: @VidathaKaruppan Is that the exact code you are using? And what does `var_dump($str);` give you?

Comment: Yes that's the same code and var_dump($str) prints :-string '8AEBB779B8564E84F8F22541DDB098D00F194D0530BF7540
' (length=50)

Comment: @VidathaKaruppan You only have 48 characters in that string that are hexadecimal. You should `trim()` the string as it looks like you have 2 white-spaces at the end.

Comment: I am sure I obtain $str as string because I can use all the string functions except hex2bin that is required

Comment: Thank you very much this saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `hex2bin()` doesn't convert strings to hexadecimal.
You should use `base_convert()` instead.

The code should be something like that:

```
base_convert($str, 16, 10);
```

Where the `16` is the current base os the string and `10` is the desired base to conversion.

More info at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Comment: Thanks :) but I have conveyed my question wrongly to you

Comment: My aim is to decrypt the hexadecimal string I have.For this I need to convert the given hexadecimal string into normal character string.

Comment: As php needs string and decryption happens correctly when the hex string is converted to normal string

Comment: Thank you :) error was inside the hex string.It contained white spaces using trim solved the problem